How do I sort multiple columns in a dataframe, if one column requires a specific mapping?
I have a dataframe where I want to sort it based on 3 columns, where one column in particular has a specific mapping I want to use. For example, for this dataframe:

I want to sort it by the columns Code, Item, and Type, but in particular I want to sort Type by a particular mapping such that it goes Admin, Staff, User, Customer (since I know that the Item and Code column will always have at least 4 of the same values (such as 1 and 2 in the example given), this shouldn't be an issue). So as the end result, I want my dataframe to look like this:

In Python, I know how to sort by multiple columns, and I also know how to sort by a particular mapping, but I don't know how to do both at the same time, so if anyone could provide some help I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Map a sorting key and use the stable sort. You can find examples that does that here and here.

Code
use key parameter of sort_values func
# your order of Type column
order = ['Admin', 'Staff', 'User', 'Customer']

# make mapper of your Type column order 
m = {key: n for n, key in enumerate(order)}

# sort by Code, Item and mapped Type column
out = df.sort_values(
    ['Code', 'Item', 'Type'], 
    key=lambda x: x.map(m) if x.name == 'Type' else x
)

out
  Code  Item      Type
3  AAA     1     Admin
2  AAA     1     Staff
1  AAA     1      User
0  AAA     1  Customer
6  AAA     2     Admin
4  AAA     2     Staff
5  AAA     2      User
7  AAA     2  Customer
8  BBB     1      User

Example Code
provide example in code or text, not image.
import pandas as pd

data = {'Code': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB'],
        'Item': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
        'Type': ['Customer', 'User', 'Staff', 'Admin', 'Staff', 'User', 'Admin', 'Customer', 'User']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


You can use ordered categorical:
cats = ['Admin', 'Staff', 'User', 'Customer']

out = (df.assign(Type = pd.Categorical(df['Type'], ordered=True, categories=cats))
         .sort_values(['Code', 'Item', 'Type']))
print (out)
  Code  Item      Type
3  AAA     1     Admin
2  AAA     1     Staff
1  AAA     1      User
0  AAA     1  Customer
6  AAA     2     Admin
4  AAA     2     Staff
5  AAA     2      User
7  AAA     2  Customer
8  BBB     1      User

Or:
cats = ['Admin', 'Staff', 'User', 'Customer']

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=cats, ordered=True)

out = (df.assign(Type = df['Type'].astype(cat_type))
         .sort_values(['Code', 'Item', 'Type']))
print (out)
  Code  Item      Type
3  AAA     1     Admin
2  AAA     1     Staff
1  AAA     1      User
0  AAA     1  Customer
6  AAA     2     Admin
4  AAA     2     Staff
5  AAA     2      User
7  AAA     2  Customer
8  BBB     1      User

